# Rename every other file

Tags: automator

I have quite some files I'd like to get renamed (Too many to do it manually), normally I'd use Automator but the thing is, I need every other file to be called the same as the file before it, but with a `2` instead of `1`

This is my files so far

```
xxx - 401a - yyy.zzz
xxx - 401b - yyy.zzz
xxx - 402a - yyy.zzz
xxx - 402b - yyy.zzz
xxx - 403a - yyy.zzz
```

And so on, but I'd like to rename them to something like

```
xxx - 401-pt1.zzz
xxx - 401-pt2.zzz
xxx - 402-pt1.zzz
xxx - 402-pt2.zzz
xxx - 403-pt1.zzz
```

Anyway to do this with automator? Asking because I've really rarely use Automator, meaning I'm not exactly what you'd call an expert.

EDIT: This is what I'm trying to achieve: http://wiki.plexapp.com/index.php/Media_Naming_and_Organization_Guide#Stacked_Episodes

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know anything about that tool than you won't mind using something else? How about a simple shell command?

Here is the same operation in Bash in increasing level of genericity. You probably don't care for the first two as it has hardcoded yyy's and zzz's but I did it to show you around [**the sed command**](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) a bit to understand the third one.

```
for file in * ; do mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed 's/a - yyy/-pt1/g')"; mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed 's/b - yyy/-pt2/g')"; done

for file in * ; do mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed 's/a - .*.zzz/-pt1.zzz/g')"; mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed 's/b - .*.zzz/-pt2.zzz/g')"; done

for file in * ; do mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed -r 's/a - .*.([a-z]{3})/-pt1.\1/')"; mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed -r 's/b - .*.([a-z]{3})/-pt2.\1/')"; done
```

There must be many other ways with other commands, of course.
You'll get unimportant errors because the mv is done twice on the whole batch.

Comment: It looks like @Sébastien Dawans has put considerable effort into his proposed solution which I plan to study and learn from, but first, I'd like to warn you about this remark: > You'll get unimportant errors because the mv is done twice on the whole batch. I don't believe that it's wise to ignore errors -- or even ignore warnings when programming in general. I'll get back to you with more ideas of how to understand bash shell scripting.

Comment: hi thanks for the comment
I mentioned that "error", which comes from the fact that the mv is done twice in a row on the output of the file listing. On the second iteration, the files previously moved are non-existant anymore. There's certainly a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work... Getting this every time I try `sed: illegal option -- r` `usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...] sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]` `mv: rename Adventure Time - 213-pt2 - Mortal Recoil {C_P} (720p).mkv to : No such file or directory`